# PHP prechecked check boxes from a String

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox, explode, checked

Hello
I would like to tell you that I know there are lots of solved example on stack overflow regarding the same issues.But mine is different and complex.
I have Php Variable that has comma separated values like **"car_ferrari,car_jaguar,car_lamborghini"**  and I have multiple check-boxes
[image]     name='car [ ] '      value = ' car_ferrari '    
[image]     name='car [ ] '      value = ' car_lamborghini '    
[image]     name='car [ ] '      value = ' car_hummer '    
[image]     name='car [ ] '      value = ' car_jaguar '    
[image]     name='car [ ] '      value = ' car_aston '

I want to checked the checbox if this variable has the same value of string.

Like checkbox with the value of **car_ferrari,car_jaguar,car_lamborghini should be checked**
I have large number of these types of variables as well as large number of checkboxes array.I know I **can use explode and then in_array()** but it is really time consuming to put condition in for each and every checkbox for around 400 checkboxes.

**if Jquery will help to sort it out ,I will use it but give me the appropriate answer.Ask me incase of query.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to split your string by comma then iterate over that and match with your check boxes.

Comment: Pass the string into jQuery and then use that to iterate through your values and check the required checkboxes.

Comment: Please check it out the url [link]http://www.codenomad.biz/ssa-agency/info and click on **genetic history**
I have each variable for each row, and I want to check the checkbox who has the same value of the the checkbox.
Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Did my suggested solution solve your problem?

Comment: @Webbanditten...sorry, but No

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a JSFiddle that demonstrates how to split the string by comma and then iterating and selecting the checkboxes with the corresponding value.

## Pure JS Solution

```js
var myString = "car_ferrari,car_jaguar,car_lamborghini";

var selectedCarArray = myString.split(",");

selectedCarArray.forEach(function(element) {
    document.getElementById('checkbox_' + element).checked = true;
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="car[]" value="car_ferrari" id="checkbox_car_ferrari" />
<input type="checkbox" name="car[]" value="car_lamborghini" id="checkbox_car_lamborghini" />
<input type="checkbox" name="car[]" value="car_hummer" id="checkbox_car_hummer" />
<input type="checkbox" name="car[]" value="car_jaguar" id="checkbox_car_jaguar" />
<input type="checkbox" name="car[]" value="car_aston" id="checkbox_car_aston" />
```

## jQuery Solution

```js
var myString = "car_ferrari,car_jaguar,car_lamborghini";

var selectedCarArray = myString.split(",");

selectedCarArray.forEach(function(element) {
    $('input[value="' + element + '"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="car[]" value="car_ferrari" />
<input type="checkbox" name="car[]" value="car_lamborghini" />
<input type="checkbox" name="car[]" value="car_hummer" />
<input type="checkbox" name="car[]" value="car_jaguar" />
<input type="checkbox" name="car[]" value="car_aston" />
```

Comment: Did you check the Url that I have provided you.
I have large number of php variables, like "shoes_adidas,shoes_reebok,shoes_nike"
and I have multiple check-boxes that has 
What if i have large number of php variables and large set of check-boxes.
 I cant use static value like var myString = "car_ferrari,car_jaguar,car_lamborghini";

Comment: I get redirected when accessing your URL.

Comment: username : manpreet@codenomad.net
pass: manpreet@123
it is just a dummy data

Comment: But Boyka, if you generate the form based on the backend data. How come you dont just mark the checkboxes checked on the backend? Why parse the extra data to the client and making it do the job of checking the input boxes?

Comment: actually I have just completed this task, there are around 15-16 tables in the db in which this tabs values are storing.I just combine this value from the database in **comma separated values** and then convert it into JQuery array and then use of inArray() that if checkbox value is in the array then it will checked else not.
Thanks for your response....Buddy

Comment: I am storing multiple checbox value is in array and then convert it into string while storing into DB.